# how to use a default MO file

Tags: localization

I've created a plugin that uses `gettext` to localize the strings. 
Here is a sample line of code from my plugin:

```
__("not less than ",'mytextdomain')
```

I realize that `not less than` is actually the identifier, not the real string, but gettext outputs that if it doesn't find the MO file for the current locale.

Now I'd like to use *real* identifiers, and have gettext output the string from a default MO file if it doesn't find the one for the current locale.

How do I set one of the MO files to be the default one? Seems strange to me, but I've googled for "gettext default locale" and similar things without luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful: `not less than` is **not** the identfier, but indeed the real English string that should be used by default. In WordPress, you'd use it like this:

`__( 'Hello World', 'mytextdomain' );`

If someones translates it into `de_DE`, they would translate `Hello World` to `Hallo Welt`.

To answer your question: the default locale in WordPress is en_US. So you could theoretically add a `en_US.mo` file that "translates" your default text. However, since en_US is the default, it's not needed nor recommended.

Let me know if you need more help with i18n inside WordPress and I'll happily extend my answer.